# Condições com typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando fazer um `if` no typescript mas ele simplesmente é ignorado e nunca entra na condição.

Meu código typescript:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-jogomemoria',
  templateUrl: 'jogomemoria.html',
})
export class JogomemoriaPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}


  vira1() {
    document.getElementById("virada0").style.zIndex = "999";
    verificaViradasCima++;
  }


  if (verificaViradasCima = 2) {
    alert("Voce clicou duas vezes");
  }
}
var verificaViradasCima = 0;
```

Por que isso acontece ?

Comment: Sempre que utilizar o código aqui no *live snippet* formate-o clicando no botão "Organizar" que aparece na barra esquerda. Isso facilita bastante a leitura para qualquer pessoa que queira responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve definir as variáveis no método `constructor`, veja esse exemplo:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Olá {{name}}</h1><button (click)="exeDecrementar()">Decrementar</button>{{verificaViradasCima}}<button (click)="exeIncrementar()">Incrementar</button>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    // Lembrando que isso é apenas um exemplo,
    // logo você deve alterar conforme sua necessidade
    constructor() {
        // Declara as variáveis.
        this.name = "Lone Tonberry";
        this.verificaViradasCima = 0;
    }

    exeDecrementar() {        
        // Se for maior que zero faz decremento.
        if (this.verificaViradasCima > 0) {
            this.verificaViradasCima--;
        }
    }

    exeIncrementar() {
        // Se for igual a 2 mostra o alerta.
        if (this.verificaViradasCima == 2) {
            alert("Voce clicou duas vezes");
        } else {
            // Se não for faz incremento.
            this.verificaViradasCima++;
        }
    }
}
```

> Você pode ver funcionando [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HXGKAYD6Vrf7LwtvwFAE?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Faltou um =...

- Use = para atribuição.
- Use == ou === para comparação.

Comment: Eu já tentei mas ele ignora da mesma forma.

Answer (score 0):

No TypeScript você pode efetuar uma atribuição durante uma comparação e isso pode gerar algum confusão (Utilizar um único sinal de igual).
Na especificação do ECMAScript, onde o JavaScript e o TypeScript são baseados, você deve utilizar dois sinais de igual para comparar se os valores de duas variáveis são equivalentes e utilizar três sinais para comparar se são iguais.

```
// O resultado é true
(1 == "1");
(1 == true);
("00.00" == 0)
(null == undefined)

// O resultado é falso
(1 === "1")
("0" === 0)
(false === 0)
```

O que == faz por trás, basicamente, é primeiramente tentar transformar os dois valores comparados em número, parece meio bizarro, mas é a vida.